# How does migrated kafka consumer behave after repartitioning while cluster migration?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have couple of conceptual doubts on the behaviour of consumers.

Cluster migration gives great opportunity while repartition topics which are over partitioned or under partitioned in current cluster.

1. So in this case of repartitioning in destination cluster, offset to
   records mapping is not going to be same in the destination cluster
   as of the source. Does it mean consumer cannot resume the job from
   target cluster from where it is left in source cluster as
   __consumer-offsets will not have same mapping?
2. Replicator uses offset translation using timestamp, does that help
   in this case.? If yes, replicator’s translation can’t be used for
   clients other than Java clients. How can I manage this scenario for
   other than Java clients?
3. I am not sure if cluster linking allows you to repartition as it is
   a byte-to-byte copy. Can you please help me understand this as well?
   Does MM2 have any configurations to cover this?

Please help me understand this, thank you.

Comment: MirrorMaker2 (and Replicator) support Connect SMTs and client interceptors, so should support repartitioning, if necessary, but it will probably break any mirrored __consumer-offsets partition information, yes

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I am in doubt of the same.

Comment: Also, since Replicator and Cluster Linking are not open source solutions, we cannot really provide more information than what's in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the migration strategy you are after, but you can correlate with the following. If you are migrating from one infra to another infra

Set **auto.offset.reset = earliest** on the consumer side, so that all newly produced events will be picked from Offset 0 of all respective partitions. Check mark should be made, where you move your Producer first and wait for all the messages drained out by the existing consumers and then move your consumers pointing to the new cluster.

And clarifying your concerns, from the documentation

1. **MirrorMaker** contains a utility class RemoteClusterUtils to enable consumers
   to seek to the last checkpointed offset in a DR cluster with offset translation when
   failing over from a primary cluster. Support for periodic migration of consumer
   offsets was added in 2.7.0 to automatically commit translated offsets to the target
   __consumer_offsets topic so that consumers switching to a DR cluster can
   restart from where they left off in the primary cluster with no data loss and minimal duplicate processing. Consumer groups for which offsets are migrated can be
   customized, and for added protection, MirrorMaker does not overwrite offsets if
   consumers on the target cluster are actively using the target consumer group,
   thus avoiding any accidental conflicts.
2. **Mirror‐Maker**, uses a Kafka topic for storing offset translation metadata. Offsets are stored whenever the difference between the two offsets changes. For example, if offset 495 on the primary mapped to offset 500 on the DR cluster, we’ll record (495,500) in the external store or offset translation topic. If the difference changes later due to duplicates and offset 596 is mapped to 600, then we’ll record the new mapping (596,600). There is no need to store all the offset mappings between 495 and 596; we just assume that the difference remains the same and so offset 550 in the primary cluster will map to 555 in the DR. Then when failover occurs, instead of mapping timestamps (which are always a bit inaccurate) to offsets, we map primary offsets to DR offsets and use those. One of the two techniques listed previously can be used to force consumers to start using the new
   offsets from the mapping.
3. No. **MirrorMaker** periodically checks for new topics in the source cluster and starts mirroring these topics automatically if they match the configured patterns. If more partitions are added to the source topic, the same number of partitions is
   automatically added to the target topic, ensuring that events in the source topic
   appear in the same partitions in the same order in the target topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am looking for cluster migration of OnPrem Kafka to Confluent cloud and I am interested in fact if I repartition my topic in target cluster and then move the data from source cluster to target. Committed offsets are not going to be the same right? OR it has mapping which takes care of everything?

And how does that affect consumer groups? Do we have any work around to resolve if mapping isn't there? And I wanted to understand for all 3 options - MM2, Replicator and Cluster Linking.